# Min-max inequality with sum of functions

Tags: inequality, optimization, summation

For some reason, I am blanking on this simple problem.  Does the following expression always hold?

$$\max_x f(x) + \min_y g(y) \leq \max_z f(z) + g(z)$$

I'm not sure that it does, but I'm having trouble proving the situation either way.  If it doesn't hold, how can I place better lower bounds on

$$\max_z f(z) + g(z)$$

than the obvious $$\min_x f(x) + \min_y g(y)$$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The inequality is true. For every $z$ we have
$$
f(z) + g(z)\ge f(z) + \min_z g(z).
$$
Taking the max over $z$ we get (since $\min g(z)$ is a constant)
$$
\max_z\left( f(z) + g(z)\right)\ge \max_z f(z) + \min_z g(z).
$$
Change the dummy variables on the RHS and you get the result.

(Strictly speaking, we should be using $\sup$, $\inf$ instead of $\max$, $\min$, unless the common domain of $f$ and $g$ is finite.)

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Comment: @grand_chat you may have been implying this already, but when you say finite you mean compact, correct?

Comment: @Paul No, I really meant finite. If there are a finite number of $z$'s to consider, then the max and min are guaranteed to exist. If not, then we have to switch to sup and inf. Even if the domain is compact the max and min may not exist (for example if $f$ has a discontinuity where the max would occur).

Comment: I do not believe this proof is entirely correct (or complete, at least). In the first inequality, we have $f(z) + g(z) \geq f(z) + const$. However, the second inequality, you wrote $f(z_1) + g(z_1) \geq f(z_2) + const$, where $z_1 = \arg\max_z (f(z) + g(z))$ and $z_2 = \arg\max_z f(z)$. Since $z_1$ is not necessarily equal to $z_2$, the second inequality does not follow directly from the first one. Just to be clear, I know the final inequality is true. I am just arguing the proof presented is not correct.

Comment: @durdi The standard proof that $A(z)\ge B(z)\ \forall z$ $\Rightarrow$ $\max A(z)\ge \max B(z)$ is to observe that $\max_z A(z)$ is an upper bound for every $B(z)$, hence $\max A(z)\ge \max B(z)$. Alternatively, using your $z_1$ and $z_2$, you argue $\max_z A(z)=A(z_1)\ge A(z_2) \ge B(z_2)=\max_z B(z)$.